# Youtube iframe не загружается

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube

Есть javascript код:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe width="200px" height="200px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/KUh2O8HylUM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<button> Start Player</button>

<script>
  $('button').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('iframe').attr('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/KUh2O8HylUM?autoplay=1');
    }, 10000);
  });
</script>
```

При клике на кнопку, срабатывает тайм аут в 10 секунд, послe, javascript меняет autoplay youtube iframe на 1 и стартует видео.

Все хорошо работает, только вот работает если пользователь в данный момент находится на странице на которой происходит действие.

Т.к если я нажму кнопку и перейду на другую вкладку
 - Тайм аут сработает, а вот видео с youtube играть не начнет. 
 - Только если вернусь обратно на страницу.

Кто знает в чем причина и как с этим бороться ?

Может как то с имитировать присутствие пользователя на странице либо что то в этом вроде.

Comment: Другая вкладка браузера или самого сайта?

Comment: По моему это защита от накрутки просмотров, не?

Comment: другая вкладка браузера

Comment: Это делает сам браузер (хром), намеренно. Не уверен, что это можно убрать. Ещё маловероятнее, что это можно убрать в чужом фрейме.

Comment: Это происходит потому что ты делаешь все неправильно. И дело тут не в политике ютюба. Пока ты находишь в другой вкладке, браузер не рендерит скрытые вкладки. Тебе надо использовать YuoTube Player API, чтоб получить контроль над плеером. Вот ссылка на документацию, доработай свой код и все получится.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=ru

Comment: Это не ответ, в данный момент у меня есть более 200 строк кода в котором также используется youtube api, я привел простой пример, чтобы можно было проверить этот код у себя, и понять как это можно решить.

Comment: `iframe` умирающая технология, используется уже редко, все делается через API и далее вряд ли что-то изменится в пользу `iframe`

Comment: Youtube Api сам вставляет свой iframe в блок, я через него собственно и делаю как написал выше, просто привел простой пример чего именно хочу добиться

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий вариант: https://jsfiddle.net/o1yxdpfr/1/

Как только iframe загружается, сразу же его запускаю и ставлю на паузу (iframe в это время невидим). После этого с видео можно работать, независимо от активности вкладки.

```
<div class="container hidden">
  <div id="player"></div>
  <button id="start">Start</button>
</div>
<style>
  .hidden
  {
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script>
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
  {
    let isFirst = true;

    window.p = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: 360,
      width: 640,
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        onReady: (e)=> e.target.playVideo(),
        onStateChange: (e)=>
        {
          if (e.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && isFirst)
          {
            isFirst = false;
            e.target.stopVideo();
            document.querySelector('.container').classList.remove('hidden');
          } 
        }
      }
    });
  }

  start.addEventListener('click', ()=>
  {
    setTimeout(()=> p.playVideo(), 10000);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: не совсем то что нужно, мне нужно кликнуть и начать отсчет в 10 секунд, переключиться на другую вкладку, и чтобы iframe загрузился и запустился пока я в другой вкладке, после окончания 10 секунд, проблема в том что, iframe не загружается пока находишься на другой вкладк

Answer (score 0):

[Это особенность работы браузеров](https://itc.ua/blogs/chrome-nachnet-stavit-vosproizvedenie-audio-video-na-pauzu-pereklyucheniya-na-vkladku/) - ваша задача не реализуема.

> Теперь при открытии на фоновой вкладке любой страницы с медиафайлом автовоспроизведение будет ставиться на паузу. Например, видео на Youtube начнет загружаться сразу, однако воспроизведение и одновременно звук появятся только после переключения на вкладку.

Comment: это не ответ, повторюсь еще раз, я пользую api но в данном примере описал проще то что мне надо, что iframe начал играть после timeout когда пользователь находится на другой вкладке, и возможно ли это, ответ не принимаю

Comment: @S1lllver прочтите, https://itc.ua/blogs/chrome-nachnet-stavit-vosproizvedenie-audio-video-na-pauzu-pereklyucheniya-na-vkladku/

Comment: прочел,  т.к я так понял, это никак не возможно обойти ?

Comment: @S1lllver нет, это особенность работы браузеров, принудительно заставить вести браузер по другому - не получится.